# Creating VMs fails on "Install VM Components" from a template using SCVMM 2008 R2

Tags: hyper-v, virtual-machines, scvmm

We are using System Center Virtual Machine Manager 2008 R2 trying to allow creation of VMs using templates. The two computers involved are **HQ-VMM1** (Server 2008 R2 Enterprise SP1, running SCVMM) and **HQ-VM2** (Server 2008 R2 Datacenter SP1, running the Hyper-V role).

Whenever we create a VM from a template using either from SCVMM Admin Console or the Self-Service Portal, the job stops on "Install VM Components" and after a few minutes we get the error:

> Error (2927)
>   A Hardware Management error has occurred trying to
>   contact server HQ-VM2.domain.local.   (Unknown error (0x80338029))
>
> Recommended Action
>   Check that WinRM is installed and running on server
>   HQ-VM2.domain.local. For more information use the command "winrm helpmsg
>   hresult".

When I check the Hyper-V console on HQ-VM2, the virtual machine has been created but it has not been set up at all, and I cannot start it from the self-service portal (I can start it directly from the Hyper-V console, though).

Things I have tried:

- I've found [this article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/jonjor/archive/2009/01/09/winrm-windows-remote-management-troubleshooting.aspx) describing how to troubleshoot WinRM. It was not previously running on HQ-VM2, but running `winrm quickconfig` fixed that. I also made sure it was running on HQ-VMM1. I opened a command prompt on HQ-VMM1 and ran `winrm id -r:hq-vm2` to make sure the WinRM service was accessible, and I received an IdentifyResponse message.
- I have run Windows Update on both machines, there are no pending updates left.
- I've run the SCVMM Configuration Analyzer and it only recommends applying the [latest hotfixes](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2397711), which I have done, and warning that the reporting server is not on HQ-VMM1.
- One site suggested that a template created in an older version of SCVMM would fail in this manner, so I created a new template but got the same result.

I'm at a loss where to go from here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over the weekend we had a power outage, and after all the servers restarted on Monday, this just worked immediately.

I know I rebooted HQ-VM2 and HQ-VMM1; I'm not sure what might have been the problem. I'll be sure to update my answer if I figure it out.  Now I just feel silly that it was clearly something dumb.

Comment: possibly a patch that had not fully installed until after the reboot?

Answer (score 0):

"A Hardware Management error has occurred trying to contact server HQ-VM2.domain.local."

May be a hint that this might be a name resolution situation - "HQ-VM2.domain.local." Have you tried utilizing its:

- IP address
- FQDN

Comment: The name resolves properly. "HQ-VM2.domain.local" is the FQDN. SCVMM already can contact HQ-VM2 because I can check its status and send control messages to it.

Comment: Have you tried the IP for the remote chance that it makes a difference in this situation - if the error message is actually accurate?

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated your SCVMM R2 to SP1?  That's probably required also.

Comment: Yes, SCVMM was updated to SP1.

Comment: Are all services that are set to "Automatically" start, running on the vm hosts?